# layout buttons are not the same size in android

Tags: android, button, layout

I have two questions, the first is that I would like the buttons to be on the bottom corner of the screen stacked like they are (they currently are in the middle) and I would like them to be the same size, currently the top 2 buttons are bigger then the bottom two buttons. Also maybe lowering the texview boxes down a little if that is easy enough. [image: Picture of emulator running for perspective]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/playerLifeOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:minWidth="120dp"
            android:text="20"
            android:textSize="40dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <Button
                android:id="@+id/badd1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="+1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/badd5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="+5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bsub1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bsub5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/playerLifeTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:minWidth="120dp"
            android:text="20"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2add1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="+1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2add5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="+5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2sub1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2sub5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-5" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/playerLifeOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:minWidth="120dp"
            android:text="20"
            android:textSize="40dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/badd1"
           android:layout_width="78dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="+1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/badd5"
               android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bsub1"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bsub5"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/playerLifeTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:minWidth="120dp"
            android:text="20"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2add1"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2add5"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2sub1"
               android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2sub5"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-5" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how can you make it so the buttons fil the screen to the line in the middle

Answer (score 0):

All buttons should look like this one.-

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/badd5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="+5" />
```

Check `layout_width` and `layout_weight` properties.

---

As for the `EditTexts`, you have several options, an easy one would be applying some top margin.-

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/playerLifeOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:text="20"
    android:textSize="40dp" >
```

Comment: Both of your answers worked for me, thank you. one last question, How do I change from landscape to port? I have the same XML file in both the layout-land folder and the layout folder but it does not currently work with two xml files

Answer (score 0):

just a tip: using a `RelativeLayout` would give you more flexibility and a more simple possibility to achieve what you need.

Note: in my sample project the `Holo.Light` theme is applied, that's why it looks a bit different.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!-- this is a SAMPLE layout. Adjust the values as you need them. -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:ems="10" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<!-- do the same thing on the right side -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMinOneLeft"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="-1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMinFiveLeft"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnMinOneLeft"
    android:text="-5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlusOneLeft"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnMinOneLeft"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="+1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlusFiveLeft"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnMinFiveLeft"
    android:text="+5" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnPlusOneLeft"/>
```

[image]